# Подсветка синтаксиса sass в visual studio code

Tags: javascript, sass, scss

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здравствуйте, такая проблема, визуал студио читает scss,а не sass,кто нибудь сталкивался с подобным?в выкатном меню нету sass. Как подключить подсветку этого синтаксиса?

Comment: Поставьте расширение, оно так и называется Sass

Answer (score 1):

В списке поддерживаемых типов VS нету sass.
Вы можете ассоциировать подсветку синтаксиса с другим файлом. 
Откройте файл, и нажмите `Ctrl + K` и затем `М`. И из появившегося списка выберите нужную ассоциацию.

Либо можете добавить расширение `Live Sass Compiler` по этой [ссылке](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.live-sass)